# Confusion regarding a basic differential equation problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Note that this question is from the 2006 AP Calculus AB examination.

Consider the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1+y}{x}$$ where $x \neq 0$. Find the particular solution with initial condition $f(-1) = 1$ and state its domain.

**My attempt**: What I did was simply solve this by *inspection*. The linear function $y=cx-1$ satisfies this clearly so long as $x \neq 0$. Hence the answer should be $y = -2x - 1$ for all $x \neq 0$.

However, according to the examination solution, the domain should be restricted to $x<0$. Am I making an error?

If it is of any utility, here is the link to the official solutions: http://apcentral.collegeboard.com/apc/public/repository/_ap06_calcab_sg.pdf

Comment: Note that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not defined at $x=0$. From the initial condition, we can only determine the function in a *connected* interval where the derivative exists and that contains the initial value of $x$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for the response. But I'm still slightly confused since the function $f$, defined for all real numbers except zero, given by $f(x) = -2x - 1$ satisfies both the initial condition and the given differential equation for all $x$ in its domain. Can you expand on why it is wrong?

Comment: Notice that $f(x)=-2x-1$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=x-1$ for $x>0$ is also a solution.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: For a simpler related example, note that $y=-\frac{1}{x}+88$ for $x\lt 0$, and $=-\frac{1}{x}+2$ for $x\gt 0$ satisfies the simple DE $\frac{dy}{dx}=1/x^2$, with initial condition $g(1)=1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is this a matter of convention?

Comment: Mostly a matter of fact. The convention part is that one ordinarily chooses the largest domain in which the initial value determines the function.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Well, you and I both agree that , let's say your example since it's simpler, satisfies the DE and the initial condition. If it satisfies, what is (factually) wrong with the answer? Sorry if my questions are really basic, but when I interpret a differential equation with an initial condition, I think it has "such and such derivative at this $(x,y)$ coordinate" and has this particular point on its graph.

Comment: "Find **the** particular solution" means we need to restrict the domain, since if we do not restrict it there are infinitely many solutions.  If it said "Find a solution" then yours would be a correct answer, except at $0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Okay, I see, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies for reading the question incorrectly.

Your method of inspection has worked. After either doing that or separating the variables and integrating, we find that $y=2|x|-1$. To find the domain, we must consider our initial value.

However, we also find that $y=-2x-1$, as our initial value also satisfies this function.

Thus, we can consider the derivative of our two functions.

If $y=2|x|-1$, then $y'=\frac{2x}{|x|}.$
If $y=-2x-1$, then $y'=-2$. Now, we can equate our derivatives to determine the domain.

$$-2=\frac{2x}{|x|}.$$

Since the LHS is always less than zero, we must conclude that the domain is $x<0$, since the derivative is not defined at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of the equation as given excludes the vertical line $\{(x,y):x=0\}=\{0\}×\Bbb R$. Consequently, any solution of this ODE can not pass that line. Since the initial point is in the left half plane, the solution is only defined for $x<0$.